# How to serialize SQL records into JavaScript objects given aliased properties

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript

This isn't much of a question, but more of a solution, as I have not been able to find anything out there on this topic.

I am building an ORM model in JavaScript, and the biggest issue I was having was serializing returned records into a format that a User would expect.

It's easy to serialize objects that were queried from a single table, however, serializing records queried from joined tables makes it pretty difficult, as it is a single-depth object containing the results.

Take the following query result for example:

```js
[
  {
      PlaylistId: 1,
      Name: 'Music',
      PlaylistTracks_PlaylistId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_TrackId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_TrackId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Name: 'For Those About To Rock (We Salute You)',
      PlaylistTracks_Track_AlbumId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_MediaTypeId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_GenreId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Composer: 'Angus Young, Malcolm Young, Brian Johnson',
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Milliseconds: 343719,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Bytes: 11170334,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_UnitPrice: '0.99'
    },
    {
      PlaylistId: 1,
      Name: 'Music',
      PlaylistTracks_PlaylistId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_TrackId: 2,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_TrackId: 2,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Name: 'Balls to the Wall',
      PlaylistTracks_Track_AlbumId: 2,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_MediaTypeId: 2,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_GenreId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Composer: null,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Milliseconds: 342562,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Bytes: 5510424,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_UnitPrice: '0.99'
    },
    {
      PlaylistId: 1,
      Name: 'Music',
      PlaylistTracks_PlaylistId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_TrackId: 3,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_TrackId: 3,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Name: 'Fast As a Shark',
      PlaylistTracks_Track_AlbumId: 3,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_MediaTypeId: 2,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_GenreId: 1,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Composer: 'F. Baltes, S. Kaufman, U. Dirkscneider & W. Hoffman',
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Milliseconds: 230619,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_Bytes: 3990994,
      PlaylistTracks_Track_UnitPrice: '0.99'
    },
]
```

Assuming you also have access to the keys that were joined on and information telling you about the type of relationship, (one-to-one or one-to-many)...

How would it be possible to serialize that into something like this?

```js
[
  {
    "PlaylistId": 1,
    "Name": "Music",
    "PlaylistTracks": [
      {
        "PlaylistId": 1,
        "TrackId": 1,
        "Track": {
          "TrackId": 1,
          "Name": "For Those About To Rock (We Salute You)",
          "AlbumId": 1,
          "MediaTypeId": 1,
          "GenreId": 1,
          "Composer": "Angus Young, Malcolm Young, Brian Johnson",
          "Milliseconds": 343719,
          "Bytes": 11170334,
          "UnitPrice": "0.99"
        }
      },
      {
        "PlaylistId": 1,
        "TrackId": 2,
        "Track": {
          "TrackId": 2,
          "Name": "Balls to the Wall",
          "AlbumId": 2,
          "MediaTypeId": 2,
          "GenreId": 1,
          "Composer": null,
          "Milliseconds": 342562,
          "Bytes": 5510424,
          "UnitPrice": "0.99"
        }
      },
      {
        "PlaylistId": 1,
        "TrackId": 3,
        "Track": {
          "TrackId": 3,
          "Name": "Fast As a Shark",
          "AlbumId": 3,
          "MediaTypeId": 2,
          "GenreId": 1,
          "Composer": "F. Baltes, S. Kaufman, U. Dirkscneider & W. Hoffman",
          "Milliseconds": 230619,
          "Bytes": 3990994,
          "UnitPrice": "0.99"
        }
      },
   ...
]
```

That's where it took me a while, working with random solutions. Eventually I got to something that felt like it worked, but edge cases were still there for weirdly configured related tables.

Finally, I approached a nice solution. Here it is

```js
    /**
     * Recursively maps relating records into a single record.
     * @param {any[]} records All records returned from a SQL query.
     * @param {any} record Record that is being worked on (this is handled recursively)
     * @param {string} prepend String to prepend onto the key for the original record's value.
     * @returns {(record: any) => TTableModel} Function for use in a JavaScript `<Array>.map()` function for use on an array of the records filtered to only uniques by main primary key.
     */
    #map(records, record=records[0], prepend="") {
        return r => {
            /** @type {any} */
            const mapping = {};
            const processedTables = new Set();
            for(const key in record) {
                const [table] = key.split("_");
                if(processedTables.has(table)) continue;
                processedTables.add(table);
                if(table === key) {
                    mapping[key] = r[`${prepend}${key}`];
                } else {
                    const entries = Object.keys(record).map(k => k.startsWith(`${table}_`) ? [k.replace(`${table}_`, ""), {}] : [null, null]).filter(([k]) => k != null);
                    if (this.#state.relationships[table].type === "1:1") {
                        const map = this.#map(records, Object.fromEntries(entries), `${prepend}${table}_`);
                        mapping[table] = map(r);
                    } else {
                        const pKey = this.#state.relationships[table].primaryKey;
                        const fKey = this.#state.relationships[table].foreignKey;
                        const map = this.#map(records, Object.fromEntries(entries), `${prepend}${table}_`);
                        mapping[table] = records.filter(_r => r[pKey] === _r[`${prepend}${table}_${fKey}`]).map(map);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return mapping;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Serializes a given array of records, `records`, into object notation that a User would expect.
     * @param {any[]} records Records to filter.
     * @returns {TTableModel[]}
     */
    #serialize(records) {
        if (records.length <= 0) return records;
        console.log({records});
        const map = this.#map(records);
        return this.#filterForUniqueRelatedRecords(records).map(map);
    }

    /**
     * Filters out duplicates of records that have the same primary key.
     * @param {any[]} records Records to filter.
     * @returns {any[]} A new array of records, where duplicates by primary key are filtered out. If no primary key is defined, then `records` is returned, untouched.
     */
    #filterForUniqueRelatedRecords(records) {
        const pKey = this.#getPrimaryKey();
        if(pKey === undefined) return records;
        const uniques = new Set();
        return records.filter(r => {
            if(uniques.has(r[pKey])) {
                return false;
            }
            uniques.add(r[pKey]);
            return true;
        });
    }
```

This solution was able to query from a local database and serialize 18 playlist records with a total of 8719 track records in a whopping 261ms (milliseconds)

For insight, I store table information in an object, `#state.relationships` where each value is an object that looks like this:

```
interface Relationship {
  thisTable: string;
  thatTable: string;
  primaryKey: string;
  foreignKey: string;
  type: "1:1"|"1:n";
  included: boolean,
  schema: {[key: string]: SchemaField};
};
```

I know there's a lot of code that could be interfaced here to understand more, but the core part I was getting at was using this information to serialize records.

Comment: An SQL table consists of rows not records. The question can be a bit more clear if making a clear distinction  between SQL rows and JS records being processed.